# Editing screenshots on Windows Phone 8

Tags: 8.0

I have some problems with screenshots stored in the "*Screenshots*" album on *Windows Phone 8 (Lumia 920)*. When I try to open them with **Photolab** (or maybe **Pictures Lab**), I get an error saying unknown format.

When I open them to crop or rotate, it just reverts back to the original on save. Have anyone else encountered this?

When I use a third party app to crop it works fine and the new image is saved.

Comment: I don't know what "Photolab" is, maybe "Pictures Lab" (test-tube above a camera icon). I tried to crop with built in functionality. Cropped, saved and the picture in Screenshots folder changed.

Answer (score 1):

Screenshot files are saved as [PNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) files. I haven't tried your application, but I suspect that your third party application does not support the PNG format.